# Run shell script as different user in the linux server

Tags: linux

For example, if there are four users are defined, A, B, C, and D:

1. I would like to provide permission to user D only to run the script.
2. Others users should login to linux server and should be able to run the script as user D
3. I don't want other users (A, B, C) to know the user D password.
4. Don't want to switch user by executing SU command - This will be my last option if above is not possible.
   Is there possibility of achieving above?
   Thank you.

Comment: What about using groups? 
File owner has the access automatically, check `chown {-R} [user]{:group} [file|directory]`

Comment: The `sudo` command does not switch users. Perhaps you're thinking of `su`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thank you for notifying . yes corrected

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález  No.. sudo can do that with "sudo -u" option . check man sudo

Comment: May be it is not switching the user ..but it can run a command as  a different user.

Comment: @zappy thank you. Yes how can we run the command as different user when we don't want to expose the password to the parent user

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.